# WSO2 claim extention using custom claim handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can we add custom claims to the ID token of WSo2.(claims which are stored in the different tables of WSO2 database)?
explanation: 
The requirement is to add some additional claim values which are specific to the organizational information of the user(which will be stored in other tables and not in the user attribute table).
how do we write a custom claim handler to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom claim handler and inject the values from the claim handler. Please follow this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Claim+Handler) to know how to deploy a custom claim handler.

You can find a sample source [code](https://github.com/wso2-incubator/samples-is/tree/master/custom-claim-handler) here.