# WSO2-IS - Set default value to a Claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How can I set a default value to a claim when configuring a Service Provider on WSO2-IS carbon?

[image: Claim Configuration]

I'd like to set a default value to **userDirectory** according to environment that I've created to pass to Service Provider.

WSO2-IS 5.11.0

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not OOTB config you can achieve this. I can suggest two ways for you to try this.

1. You can do customization and get this capability. You can write a lister and subscribe to `PostAddUser` event or `PostGetUser` event. To do so you need to introduce a new claim as well.
2. IF you want to include this claim in the ID token, then you can implement a custom claim provider. Follow the [blog](https://ganganichamika.medium.com/how-to-write-custom-claim-provider-in-wso2-identity-server-c1d2c9814b84) for more details.

**Edit:**

AFAIU there is a 3rd option you can do that is explained in [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388264/wso2-claim-extention-using-custom-claim-handler), where you can define a [custom claim handler](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/extend/user-mgt/write-a-custom-claim-handler/). With this approach, the claims will be added to all the assertions.